# Arduino IDE EEPROM put() then read() returns different data on ESP32

Tags: esp32, eeprom

I'm trying to understand how to read/write [a UID struct from miguelbalboa](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.h#L255) to EEPROM to persist a card ID across system restarts on my ESP32-S3 through the Arduino IDE. I expected Put/Get/Read to be symmetrical but can't seem to prove that. Here's my test program:

```
/**
 * This is a simple script to experiment with reading and writing MFRC522::Uid
 * structures to eeprom.
 */

#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define UID_EEPROM_LOCATION 0
#define EEPROM_SIZE 256

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  Serial.println("Serial started.");
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  Serial.print("EEPROM started ");
  Serial.println(EEPROM_SIZE);
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  MFRC522::Uid uidToWrite = {
    0x04,
    {B00000000, B10000000, B11100000, B01100000},
    0
  };
  Serial.print("UID Before Write: ");
  printUid(&(uidToWrite));
  storeUidInEeprom(&(uidToWrite));
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  Serial.println("UID was put.");
  MFRC522::Uid uidFromRead;
  readUidFromEeprom(&(uidFromRead));
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  Serial.print("UID from Read: ");
  printUid(&(uidFromRead));
}

void loop() {
}

void printUid(MFRC522::Uid *uid) {
  Serial.print(uid->size, HEX);
  Serial.print(F(" byte card UID:"));
  for (byte i = 0; i < uid->size; i++) {
    if(uid->uidByte[i] < 0x10)
      Serial.print(F(" 0"));
    else
      Serial.print(F(" "));
    Serial.print(uid->uidByte[i], HEX);
  } 
  Serial.println();
}

void readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid* result) {
  EEPROM.get(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, result);
  delay(1000);
}

void storeUidInEeprom(MFRC522::Uid *uid) {
  EEPROM.put(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, uid);
  EEPROM.commit();
  delay(1000);
}

void printBytesFromEeprom() {
  Serial.print("256 bytes from EEPROM: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    byte myByte = EEPROM.read(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + i);
    if(myByte < 0x10)
      Serial.print(F(" 0"));
    else
      Serial.print(F(" "));
    Serial.print(myByte, HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I'm an experienced Java developer, but new to C++. I could have made any number of basic errors.

When I run the above on my ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1, I get the following output:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd0108,len:0x43c
load:0x403b6000,len:0xbd0
load:0x403ba000,len:0x29c8
entry 0x403b61d8
Serial started.
EEPROM started 256
256 bytes from EEPROM:  E4 2C CE 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID Before Write: 4 byte card UID: 00 80 E0 60
256 bytes from EEPROM:  94 2D CE 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID was put.
256 bytes from EEPROM:  94 2D CE 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID from Read: C0 byte card UID: 79 CD 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C FA 3B C7 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 4C 2F CE 3F 01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 F0 2D CE 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2E CE 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

There are two unexpected things from this output:

- The output of `readUidFromEeprom()` is different than the input to `storeUidInEeprom()`

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: `readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid& result)`

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

```cpp
void readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid* result) {
  EEPROM.get(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, result);
  delay(1000);
}
```

The `EEPROM.get()` method expects a *reference* to the variable you are
setting. Here, you are providing a *pointer* instead. The outcome is
that this call is updating the `result` local variable (the pointer),
rather than the memory region pointed by it.

You may try this:

```cpp
void readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid* result) {
  EEPROM.get(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, *result);  // notice the `*' operator
  delay(1000);
}
```

Same thing for `EEPROM.put()`.

**Edit**: As suggested by Juraj in a comment, it can make more sense to
have `readUidFromEeprom()` accept a reference rather than a pointer:

```cpp
void readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid &result) {
  EEPROM.get(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, result);
  delay(1000);
}
```

But then you have to also change the caller:

```cpp
readUidFromEeprom(uidFromRead);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...

I still don't know why the above wasn't working. But if I switch to my own byte encoding in EEPROM (the obvious one that I assumed `put()` used, then I get the right behavior:

```
/**
 * This is a simple script to experiment with reading and writing MFRC522::Uid
 * structures to eeprom.
 */

#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define UID_EEPROM_LOCATION 0
#define EEPROM_SIZE 256

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  Serial.println("Serial started.");
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  Serial.print("EEPROM started ");
  Serial.println(EEPROM_SIZE);
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  MFRC522::Uid uidToWrite = {
    0x04,
    {B00000000, B10000000, B11100000, B01100000},
    0
  };
  Serial.print("UID Before Write: ");
  printUid(&(uidToWrite));
  storeUidInEeprom(&(uidToWrite));
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  Serial.println("UID was put.");
  MFRC522::Uid uidFromRead;
  readUidFromEeprom(&(uidFromRead));
  printBytesFromEeprom();
  Serial.print("UID from Read: ");
  printUid(&(uidFromRead));
}

void loop() {
}

void printUid(MFRC522::Uid *uid) {
  Serial.print(uid->size, HEX);
  Serial.print(F(" byte card UID:"));
  for (byte i = 0; i < uid->size; i++) {
    if(uid->uidByte[i] < 0x10)
      Serial.print(F(" 0"));
    else
      Serial.print(F(" "));
    Serial.print(uid->uidByte[i], HEX);
  } 
  Serial.println();
}

void readUidFromEeprom(MFRC522::Uid* result) {
  byte uidSize = EEPROM.read(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION);
  for (byte i = 0; i < uidSize; i++) {
    result->uidByte[i] = EEPROM.read(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + 1 + i);
  }
  byte uidSak = EEPROM.read(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + 2 + uidSize);
  result->size = uidSize;
  result->sak = uidSak;
}

void storeUidInEeprom(MFRC522::Uid *uid) {
  EEPROM.write(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION, uid->size);
  for (byte i = 0; i < uid->size; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + 1 + i, uid->uidByte[i]);
  } 
  EEPROM.write(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + 2 + uid->size, uid->sak);
  EEPROM.commit();
}

void printBytesFromEeprom() {
  Serial.print("256 bytes from EEPROM: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    byte myByte = EEPROM.read(UID_EEPROM_LOCATION + i);
    if(myByte < 0x10)
      Serial.print(F(" 0"));
    else
      Serial.print(F(" "));
    Serial.print(myByte, HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

And output as expected is:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd0108,len:0x43c
load:0x403b6000,len:0xbd0
load:0x403ba000,len:0x29c8
entry 0x403b61d8
Serial started.
EEPROM started 256
256 bytes from EEPROM:  04 00 80 E0 60 FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID Before Write: 4 byte card UID: 00 80 E0 60
256 bytes from EEPROM:  04 00 80 E0 60 FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID was put.
256 bytes from EEPROM:  04 00 80 E0 60 FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
UID from Read: 4 byte card UID: 00 80 E0 60
```

Answer (score -1):

On the ESP23 platform, consider using the Preferences library. EEPROM in arduino-esp32 is emulated using the Preferences library. Might mess up the calls to MFRC522 lib though.

Preferences docs include the API and tutorial.